# Python OOP object instantiation

Tags: python, oop

I am new to Python, and I have one dilemma concerning OOP (I am familiar with OOP concepts).
Basically, I have a class with a static class-variable (`counter` that shows how many objects I have instantiated):

```
class Employee:
   counter=0
   def __init__(self,name):
     self.name=name
     Employee.counter+=1
```

So now I instantiate an object:

```
obj1=Employee("Alan")
```

My question is: what happens when I have this call? What happens behind, because the static variable "counter" is incremented, but it is possible to access the object created like this?

```
Employee("foo")
```

`<__main__.Employee object at 0x02A16870>`

Thanks

Comment: The `__init__` function is your constructor, so it increments `counter` whenever you create a new `Employee object.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: The code you've shown won't run. `counter` should be accessed via the instance or class

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: Why not?  Oh, I see now... `counter += 1` should be `Employee.counter += 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need `counter+=1` to be `Employee.counter += 1` in order for the code to behave like you say it does. Otherwise you will get an error for trying to increment a variable that's not known within the scope of `__init__`.

Since you have no reference to `Employee("foo")` it will soon be garbage collected and gone forever. However, this does not change the fact that `Employee.__init__` was called to increment your `counter`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put the Employee.counter += 1 . So basically since there is now reference , the garbage collector will free the heap. Thank you for theexplanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Employee("foo")
```

This object created above will be lost as soon as it is used and cannot be re-used whereas when you instantiate an object like

```
obj1=Employee("Alan")
```

you have a reference of that object in `obj1` and it can be re-used.

> My question what happens when I have this call? What happens behind

The `__init__` function is the constructor and it is called each time you create a new object of your class. As this `__init__` function increments the counter variable, so each time an object is created, `__init__` function is called and counter gets incremented.